# Change default kernel for an AWS instance running Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, linux-kernel

**1. Problem summary**
I have an instance on AWS running Ubuntu 18.04. The kernel version is 5.4.0. I have installed  kernel 4.15.0 but I am failing to set it as the default.

**2. What I have tried**

A) I set the following values in /etc/default/grub

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=y
```

and made sure there is no value for GRUB_DEFAULT in /etc/default/grub.d/50-cloudimg-settings.cfg

Created an environment variable for GRUB_CONFIG using

```
export GRUB_CONFIG=`sudo find /boot -name "grub.cfg"
```

I rebuilt grub.cfg using `sudo update-grub` and rebooted the instances, but no change in the active kernel observed from running `uname -r`.

B) I also tried the solution of deleting the kernel that I no longer want described [here] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25993363/how-to-remove-a-newly-installed-kernel) but the instance then fails status checks and I cannot connect to it using SSH.

C) I set the value for GRUB_DEFAULT to the menu_string as `GRUB_DEFAULT="gnulinux-advanced-0d5e1897-19aa-4121-b1f8-2c7e0f833c4d>gnulinux-4.15.0-20-generic-advanced-0d5e1897-19aa-4121-b1f8-2c7e0f833c4d"`, rebuilt grub.cfg using `sudo update-grub`, but still no change after rebooting.

Answer (score 3):

Open the terminal and write:

```
uname -r
```

This is your kernel version before starting. Now, let's change it!

Write in the terminal:

```
grub-install --version
```

Remember the GRUB version it's saying. Now open the file:

```
vi /boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Check what is the version you want, and take its name. For example:

> ```
>     menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-188-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.15.0-188-generic-advanced-7e6f0fb2-8fc4-4e31-92ef-912be559e099' {
>             recordfail
>             load_video
> ```

if the GRUB version you had is < 2.00 the name is:

> Advanced options for Ubuntu>Ubuntu, with Linux 4.15.0-188-generic

otherwise is:

> gnulinux-advanced-7e6f0fb2-8fc4-4e31-92ef-912be559e099>gnulinux-4.15.0-188-generic-advanced-7e6f0fb2-8fc4-4e31-92ef-912be559e099

Now, in the terminal:

```
sudo vi /etc/default/grub
```

Press key "i" in the keyboard to modify the file. Go to the line where it says GRUB_DEFAULT and paste the previous name. It should be for grub >2 (instead of GRUB_DEFAULT=0):

```
GRUB_DEFAULT="gnulinux-4.15.0-188-generic-advanced-7e6f0fb2-8fc4-4e31-92ef-912be559e099>gnulinux-4.15.0-188-generic-advanced-7e6f0fb2-8fc4-4e31-92ef-912be559e099"
```

Press key "Esc" in the keyboard. Write :wq and press enter. File has been saved. Now redo the grub. If you put it wrongly it will tell you how it should be!

```
sudo update-grub
```

Now reboot:

```
sudo reboot
```

Check your kernel version!

```
uname -r
```

I only did this, and worked for me. It's an EC2 with Ubuntu 18.04 and kernel 5.4.